# Physical meaning of the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Fractional Laplacian

Tags: mathematical-physics, differentiation

What is the physical meaning of the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the [Fractional Laplacian](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian)?

Comment: They are important for describing propeeties of fractional PDEs such as e.g. fractional diffusion equation, which describes some types of anomalous diffusion.

Comment: More on [fractional derivatives](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22fractional+derivatives%22).